# Spring unit testing and InitialContext

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, tomcat

I would like to get a simple integration test with Tomcat and Spring 4 running, injecting a spring component and use my existing data source configuration from Tomcat. I don't want to configure my DataSource twice. 
Everything, including my data source, is configured in the file `WebContent/WEB-INF/application-context.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <task:annotation-driven />

    <!-- annotations in bean classes -->
    <!-- context:annotation-config / -->

    <!-- mvc:annotation-driven / -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.package.**" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.mycompany.package.**" />


    <!-- <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/> -->

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="packagePU" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <props>
                <prop key="eclipselink.weaving">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />
    <!-- <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"> 
        <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/> </bean> -->

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames" value="i18n/messages" />
    </bean>

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB" />

</beans>
```

I am using this tutorial http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management, but I don't fully understand how I can just run my test in the context of Tomcat that provides my DataSource.

Currently, I am this far:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:WebContent/WEB-INF/application-context.xml"})
public class SimulatorTest {

    @Autowired
    private ShiftSimulator simulator;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        // ??? 

    }


    @Test
    public void testShiftStart() {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
    }

}
```

Currently, I get this error when running the test

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [file:WebContent/WEB-INF/application-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
...
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
...
```

I fully understand that there needs to be a InitialContext, but how can I provide my test with my context that is provided by Tomcat, including my Data Source configuration? I don't want to set my data source connection credentials twice.

Comment: can you paste the application-context.xml that you are using? if it is big just paste the relevant part. According to my understanding you can have everything in the xml you dont need to specify datasource twice. and you dont need to do any initialization. I have working code and i never have this problem

Comment: @user3659052 I've added the content, thank you

Comment: you dont have reference to your dataSource.
do two things. First change: <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/DefaultDB" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"  />
and Second: add <bean id="someDao" class="com.foo.JdbcUserDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>  or whatever you need to define a datasource. then this error will go away

Comment: @user3659052
Both is already there (except the expected-type, as you mentioned, but gives same error), as you can see. For the second change, take a look at entityManagerFactory where I'm referencing to the dataSource I have defined in the same file. I'm not using DAOs. The web app works fine, except the tests. It looks more like it actually fails to create the bean "dataSource" due to a missing initial context.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Just to recap the problem: Spring tries to create the `dataSource` bean and fails at looking up the JNDI name - because there is no JNDI available.

So what I did for testing, I just created another XML files that overrides the bean `dataSource`. I ignored the file in version control and ask every developer to copy this file in place:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver"
        p:url="jdbc:sap://xxx:30015"
        p:username="sa"
        p:password="">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

In the test class, I am providing the additional file reference that overrides `dataSource` so it never tries to do the failing JNDI lookup:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:WebContent/WEB-INF/application-context.xml", "file:WebContent/WEB-INF/test-datasource.xml"  })
public class SimulatorTest {
...
```

Comment: Assuming you are using maven just put it in  `src/test/resources` you shouldn't be copying files manually.

Comment: But I don't want to have my credentials in my source code repository.

Comment: Then put the credentials in a properties file that is per user on his file system (home directory). Also if it is for testing why is it so dangerous to have them you should have a test account for that and not your own or the production account. Letting developers copy something in place for testing or otherwise is error prone and eventually will bite you.

Answer (score 0):

[TomcatJNDI](https://github.com/h-thurow/TomcatJNDI) offers a comfortable solution for this problem. It's based on Tomcat's JNDI system and initializes only Tomcat's JNDI environment without starting the server. So you can access all your resources as configured in Tomcat's configuration files in tests or from within any Java SE application. Usage is simple, e. g.

```
TomcatJNDI tomcatJNDI = new TomcatJNDI();
tomcatJNDI.processContextXml(contextXmlFile);
tomcatJNDI.start();

DataSource ds = (DataSource) InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/env/path/to/datasource");
```

[Find more about it here.](https://github.com/h-thurow/TomcatJNDI)